# Can I overwrite a remote git commit?

Tags: git, github

I committed D' based on B, but some one committed/pushed C on the remote repo. I pushed my D' to the remote repo. But unfortunately I noticed the remote repo merged D with C, and C is not a good commit. But now things are done. could I regret and make the branch commits list as  A->B->D->E? By the way, there has no more new commit based on C.
[image]

Comment: Generally, you download the history, bring it into the shape you need, then force-push it back to the remote. Of course, all caveats about history rewriting apply.

Comment: @j6t Sorry. My expression was not clear. I never used force-push, just push. The question above has been edited.

Comment: **Usually** the push doesn't do an automagic merge/rebase. **If** that happened and you didn't do it explicitly, then that happened when you *pulled* from the remote, just before you pushed to it. So the fix is not to change what happens on the remote, but to change what happens when you pull. To get a more explicit answer, it's important to understand what workflow you use. Do you use pull-requests? Do you directly push to the target branch?

Comment: I directly pushed to the target branch after making a pull and merging some conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you do **not** use `--force`. A forward fix - rather than changing history - is safe and it's a good solution in almost all cases.

A forward fix could be:

1. Fix what is broken in the code and commit it. Don't worry about history; just get the code working the way it should. Solved.
2. In some cases `git revert C` is enough if you just want to get rid of `C`.